# Calculate number of years and days in mintues

Tags: java, math, time, numbers

Here is my code:

```
public class numberOfYears {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    String minsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter numbers of minutes:");
    double mins = Double.parseDouble(minsString);
    //calcuate mins in a year
    double minsOfaYear = 365*24*60;
    double total = mins / minsOfaYear;
    double year = total / 10;
    double day = total / 10;

 System.out.println(year+ " years and " + day + " days");
 //result isnt right

    }
}
```

The question is basically asking to enter minutes and the program supposedly to calculate it to years and days.. for instance, if I enter 1000000000 minutes it should give a result of 1902 years and 214 days.. but I am not getting the correct result. Can someone point out the problem for me please? Thank you!

Comment: The problem you have is the classic "no leap years" problem...This process is actually rather complicated and annoying.  Better to use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead - for example, there is actually 365.242 days per year ;)

Comment: Go through each line of code you've written, and say what you think it does.  Some lines, particularly like computing `year` and `day`, seem like you just threw some pieces together ("well, I know I need a division sign in there somewhere...") and hoped it would do something useful.  Figure out your algorithm in plain English first, then trace through it with an example and see if it works.  Only then try to translate it into code.

Comment: Thank you, I am reading my code and checking the problems again

Comment: @ Michelle you should upvote all the answers that were helpful to you, including the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class numberOfYears {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    String minsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter numbers of minutes:");
    double mins = Double.parseDouble(minsString);
   //calcuate mins in a year
    double minsOfaYear = 365*24*60;
    double year = mins / minsOfaYear;
    double day = (mins % minsOfaYear)/(24*60);
    System.out.println((int)year+ " years and " + (int)day + " days");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the remainders of time to the smaller units of time. In example remainder of years should be converted to days, and remainder of days should be converted to hours etc.

Could you please try this:

```
public class numberOfYears {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    String minsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter numbers of minutes:");
    int mins = Int.parseInt(minsString, 16);

    String time = ConvertTime(mins);

    System.out.println(time);
    }
}   

// Convert minutes to years, days, hours an minutes
public String ConvertTime(int time){
   String result = "";

   int years = time/(365*24*60);
   int days = (time%(365*24*60))/(24*60);
   int hours= (time%(365*24*60)) / 60;
   int minutes = (time%(365*24*60)) % 60;

   result = years+" years " + days + " days "+ hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes";
   return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of math problem, we need to make use of integer division. If the number of minutes works out to be 45.8 years, you want this to be calculated as 45 years and then convert the remainder of 0.8 years into days. Its not clear to me why your code has a `/ 10`

Try this:

```
public class numberOfYears {
   static double minsOfaYear = 365*24*60;

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String minsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter numbers of minutes:");
      double mins = Double.parseDouble(minsString);
      //calcuate mins in a year
      int year = (int) (mins / minsOfaYear);
      double day = mins - year*minsOfaYear;
      System.out.println(year+ " years and " + day + " days");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you thorn. It made me clear where I have done wrong.. thank you again

Comment: How we can calculate hours in your logic ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1000000000);
    int year1 = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int day1 = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    int year2 = c2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int day2 = c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    int years;
    int days;
    if (day2 > day1) {
        years = year2 - year1;
        days = day2 - day1;
    } else {
        c2.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
        years = year2 - year1 - 1;
        days = c2.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - day1 + day2;
    }
    System.out.println(years + " years " + days + " days from now");
```

output

```
1901 years 119 days from now
```